# file_get_contents from specific URL

Tags: php, api, curl, file-get-contents

I have an API Key that verifies the request URL

If I do

```
echo file_get_contents('http://myfilelocation.com/?apikey=1234');
```

**RESULT :**  `this api key is not authorized for this domain`

However, if I put the requested URL within an iframe with the same URL:

**RESULT :**  `this api key is authorized`

Obviously, the Server I'm getting the requested JSON return data is working properly because the iframe is outputting the proper information. However, how can I verify that PHP is making the request from the proper domain and URL settings?

By using `file_get_contents` I am always getting back that the API key is not authorized. However, I'm running the php script from the authorized domain.

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn't send anything about domain. Contact the API developers about what checks they perform

Comment: IOW the API devs must be checking things like user agent to see if one exists, likely in efforts to prevent bots from making requests. You will need to use curl so that you can set things like user agent. But you will need to contact the API devs to find out what they specifically look for so that you can use the appropriate settings with curl

Answer (score 0):

**Try this PHP code:**

```
<?php
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Host: myfilelocation.com\r\n". // Don't forgot replace with your domain
              "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents("http://myfilelocation.com/?apikey=1234", false, $context);
?>
```

Comment: You should explain why this works, and why the OP's approach does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` doesn't send a any referrer information and the api may need it, this may help you:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myfilelocation.com/?apikey=1234');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://autorized-domain.here');
$html = curl_exec($ch);

echo $html;
?>
```